# Adding multiple dataframes to excel in multiple function calls to multiple sheets

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I am trying to create a function to write to excel file multiple dataframe and add sheets to dataframe for next function call.

My function looks as following:

```
def dumpMultipleDFs(dfs, fn, sheetName):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fn)
    workbook1 = writer.book
    worksheets = writer.sheets
    sr = 1
    for df in dfs:
        df.to_excel(writer, sheetName, startrow=sr)
        worksheet1 = worksheets[sheetName]
        worksheet1.write(sr - 1, 0, df.columns.name)
        sr += df.shape[0] + 4

    writer.save()
    writer.close()
```

`dfs` is list of dataframes

I trying to do the following after my function declaration in `main`:

```
fn = r'myExcel.xlsx'
dumpMultipleDFs([df1, df2, df3], fn, 'mysheet1')
dumpMultipleDFs([df4, df5, df6], fn, 'mysheet2')
```

However, only `mySheet2` shows up in `myExcel.xlsx`. How do I modify my `dumpMultipleDFs`, so that both `mySheet1` and `mySheet2` can show up in final excel file ?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html Scroll all the way down

Comment: I have already implemented the logic from link, my challenge reopening the file